# Find Z component of a 3-dimensional vector's magnitude

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

So, I'm quite confused. I'm currently working with 3-dimensional vectors in an attempt to model an object's local axes in Unity. I already understand how to find the X and Y components of said vectors' magnitudes using trigonometric functions. However, I've never worked with 3D vectors like this before. What I'm wondering is: Given an angle in radians which represents the Z axis rotation, what method could I use to calculate the Z component of the magnitude of a 3-dimensional unit vector?

Note: Constructive criticism is always appreciated. If you see any way I can improve this question, let me know!

Comment: Looking at documentation for Unity, it seems the velocity of a body is a Vector3 and you can read the coordinates of a Vector3 directly: v.x, v.y, v.z. (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) How did "component angles" come into this?

Comment: I'm trying to draw an object's local x, y, and z axes using Gizmos. My current method of approach is to draw a line extending from the center of the object, and utilize the object's rotation relative to the world space to calculate the endpoint of the line.

Comment: I suggest either you back up a few steps and rewrite your question explaining step by step how you got to the problem you want to solve, without assuming we know _anything_ about Unity, or take this question to stackoverflow where it is fair to assume there will be people who know how that software works.

Comment: Got it. I'll rewrite the question as soon as possible.

Comment: I think you might be looking for [these formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1385150/174882)