# find the coordinates of $n$-D point from $(n-1)$ angles and distance

Tags: geometry

I’m writing a program that can render $n$-D shapes, and, through the way I’m doing it, I have come to need to calculate the Cartesian coordinates of a point from $(n-1)$ angles and the distance of the point to the origin.

How can I calculate the coordinates $x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots, x_n$ from the distance $r$ and the angles $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \ldots, \alpha_n$ wherein $\alpha_m$ is the angle measured from the axis $x_0$ towards the axis $x_m$?

Note: I *have* read [Calculate 3D Vector out of two angles and vector length](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1385137), but I’m having trouble generalizing it to $n$ dimensions. Above just an answer, an explanation would really be welcome.

Comment: It's not in the english Wikipedia article for some reason, but the german one has it: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kugelkoordinaten#Verallgemeinerung_auf_n-dimensionale_Kugelkoordinaten I hope it's clear enough.

Comment: @Frank, I don't understand why, say, $x_{10}$ has more $\sin$ calculations than, say, $x_3$. I figured it'd have the same amount of calculations but with different angles. If you could post that as an answer and give an explanation, it'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $\alpha_m$ is the polar angle measured in the plane spanned by $0$-th and $m$-th basis vectors, it’s a fairly trivial exercise. We have $x_0 = r_m\cos\alpha_m$ and $x_m = r_m\sin\alpha_m$ for some $r_m$ (the length of a projection of our vector $(x_0,\ldots,x_n)$ to that plane), then also we have
$$r^2 = x_0^2 + \ldots + x_n^2 = x_0^2\left(1 + (x_1/x_0)^2 + \ldots + (x_m/x_0)^2\right) = x_0^2\left(1 + \tan^2\alpha_1 + \ldots + \tan^2\alpha_n\right),$$
assuming $x_0\ne0$. Then we have found
$$x_0 = \frac r{\sqrt{1 + \tan^2\alpha_1 + \ldots + \tan^2\alpha_n}}.$$
And then we also have found all the $x_m = x_0\tan\alpha_m$.

The case $x_0 = 0$ holds iff $\tan\alpha_m$ are undefined, and then there is an ambiguity unless $r$ is also zero (then all the coordinates are obviously zero).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Floating point will handle the case wherein $\tan \alpha_m$ is undefined for me, but thanks for mentioning it anyway. But I don't understand what you mean when you say that there is an ambiguity when $x_0 = 0$, nor do I understand why $x_m = x_0 \tan \alpha_m$.

Comment: $x_m = r_m\sin\alpha_m = (x_0/\cos\alpha_m)\sin\alpha_m$, so here’s a tangent. When $x_0 = 0, r\ne0$, all $\alpha_m$ are $\pm\pi/2$, and we can’t recover $x_m$ magnitudes—only their signs.

Comment: I was having trouble visualizing the $x_0 = 0$ case, but after actually drawing it, I can better understand the problem with it. Thanks for bothering to answer; it's really appreciated.